# How to fetch events from the Google Calendar API with a Rails JSON API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, google-calendar-api

Right now I receive an error:

> **Required parameter is missing: grant_type**

When using the `retrieve_events` controller action.

```
 module Api
  module V1
    class EventsController < ApplicationController

      require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
      require 'googleauth'
      require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'
      require 'openssl'
      require 'fileutils'


      def index
        # @events = Event.all
        # render json: @events
      end


      OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

      def retrieve_events
        client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
          client_id: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_id,
          client_secret: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_secret,
          token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
        })

        client.update!(session[:authorization])

        service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
        service.authorization = client

        @event_list = service.list_events(params[:calendar_id])
        # @event_list = service.list_events(1)

        @event_list.items.each do |event|

          unless event.start.nil?
            e = Event.find_or_initialize_by(title: event.summary)
            if event.start.date
              e.start_time = DateTime.parse(event.start.date).beginning_of_day
              e.end_time = DateTime.parse(event.start.date).end_of_day
            else
              e.start_time = event.start.date_time
              e.end_time = event.end.date_time
            end
            e.approved = true
            e.save!
          end
        end
        render json: @event_list
      end

      def new_event
        client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
          client_id: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_id,
          client_secret: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_secret,
          token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
        })

        client.update!(session[:authorization])

        service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
        service.authorization = client

        today = Date.today

        event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
          start: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(date: today),
          end: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(date: today + 1),
          summary: 'New event!'
        })

        service.insert_event(params[:calendar_id], event)

        redirect_to events_url(calendar_id: params[:calendar_id])
      end

      def redirect
        client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
          client_id: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_id,
          client_secret: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_secret,
          authorization_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
          scope: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR,
          redirect_uri: callback_url
        })

        redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s
      end

      def callback
        client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
          client_id: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_id,
          client_secret: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_secret,
          token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
          redirect_uri: callback_url,
          code: params[:code]
        })

        response = client.fetch_access_token!

        session[:authorization] = response

        redirect_to calendars_url
      end

      def calendars
        client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
          client_id: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_id,
          client_secret: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_secret,
          token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
        })

        client.update!(session[:authorization])

        service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
        service.authorization = client

        @calendar_list = service.list_calendar_lists
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In the routes this goes through:

```
collection do
  post :retrieve_events
end
```

Once this worked in a rails app that was not in API mode. Then you went through a Google console and went back authorised.

How to make this just as smooth with a JSON API visiting URL:

`api/v1/events/retrieve_events`

Comment: It would be easier if you stripped the code example to the bare minimum to reproduce the error. Also the URL used by the API client would be useful.

Comment: I've added the url at the bottom. The rest is how I have implemented the Google Calendar sample ruby code.

Comment: So the error is from the Google API? Not a Ruby exception? And if so which API call is generating the error, see my first comment, make the code example smaller, to just show relevant code.

Comment: retrieve_events

Comment: Can you rephrase your answer...

Comment: Way before I was facing a similar error getting Google Analytics to work. I remember this error. I can't speak specifically for Calendar but follow [this article](http://blog.jieck.com/server-side-integrates-google-analytics-api-with-ruby/) for getting permission. It should be easy to modify it for Calendar after you get the authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You doing it little bit wrong you have to do

```rb
@event_list = client.list_events(params[:calendar_id])
```

because you are try to fetch google user events